# MySQL - Consider multiple rows with equal value in two columns as one row

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum, distinct

Let's say I have a table with the following data:

```
Event_ID | Action_ID | Date_of_Action

   1     |     1     |  2015-06-25
   2     |     1     |  2015-06-25
   3     |     1     |  2015-04-10
   4     |     2     |  2015-05-11
```

I need to get the count of rows in this table with specific Action_ID's and display them, but I need to treat any rows with the same Action_ID AND Date_of_Action as 1 row(or 1 count).

I want it to display:

```
Count 1  | Count 2
         |
   2     |    1
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(event.Action_ID = 1, 1, 0)) AS 'Count 1',
SUM(IF(event.Action_ID = 2, 1, 0)) AS 'Count 2',
...
GROUP BY event.Action_ID, event.Date_of_Action
```

But my Output looked like this:

```
Count 1  | Count 2
         |
   3     |   1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by getting distinct action_id and date pairs like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT action_id, date_of_action
FROM myTable;
```

Once you have that, you can get count using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(action_id = 1) AS 'count 1', SUM(action_id = 2) AS 'count 2'
FROM(
   SELECT DISTINCT action_id, date_of_action
   FROM myTable) tmp;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecebc/1) example.

Comment: Works great - Thanks!
Did not know you could put that conditional inside of a SUM()

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery that combines rows with the same action ID and date:

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(event.Action_ID = 1, 1, 0)) AS 'Count 1',
SUM(IF(event.Action_ID = 2, 1, 0)) AS 'Count 2',
...
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Action_ID, Date_of_Action
      FROM event) AS event
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need them in separate columns or is it just the data you need?
If you are happy for a row per count then try

```
SELECT Action_ID, count(Event_ID)
FROM myTable
group by Action_ID, Date_of_Action
```

Comment: This does the opposite of what he wants. It counts the number of times the action_ID and date are repeated, instead of counting them as just one. BTW, it should be `COUNT(*)`, not `COUNT(Event_ID)`.